# How to remove duplicate rows with a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, drop-duplicates

i.e
i want to drop duplicates pairs using col1 and col2 as the subset only if the values are the opposite in col3 (one negative and one positive). similar to drop_duplicates function but i want to impose a condition and only want to remove the first pair (i.e if 3 duplicates, just remove 2, leave 1)

my dataset (df):

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   1        1       1
1   2        2       2
2   1        1       1
3   3        5       7
4   1        2      -1
5   1        2       1
6   1        2       1

I want:


        col1    col2    col3
    0   1        1        1
    1   2        2        2
    2   1        1        1
    3   3        5        7
    6   1        2        1
```

rows 4 and 5 are duplicated in col1 and col2 but value in col3 is the opposite, therefore we remove both. row 0 and row 2 have duplicate values in col1 and col2 but col3 is the same, so we don't remove those rows.

i've tried using drop_duplicates but realised it wouldn't work as it will only remove all duplicates and not consider anything else.

Answer (score 0):

We can do `transform`

```
out = df[df.groupby(['col1','col2']).col3.transform('sum').ne(0) & df.col3.ne(0)]
Out[252]: 
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     1     1
1     2     2     2
2     1     1     1
3     3     5     7
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code fails when a add a 6th row which has values 1,2,3 (same as the 5th row. It doesn't seem to remove any row. It should remove the 4th and 5th row still.

Answer (score 0):

Recreating the dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [1, 1,  1],
    [2, 2,  2],
    [1, 1,  1],
    [3, 5,  7],
    [1, 2, -1],
    [1, 2,  1],
    [1, 2,  1],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

if your data is not massive, you can use an `iterrows` function on a subset of the data. 
The subset contains all duplicate values after all values have been turned into absolute values. 
Next, we check if `col3` is negative and if the opposite of `col3` is in the duplicate subset. 
If so, we drop the row from `df`.

```
df_dupes = df[df.abs().duplicated(keep=False)]
df_dupes_list = df_dupes.to_numpy().tolist()
for i, row in df_dupes.iterrows():
    if row.col3 < 0 and [row.col1, row.col2, -row.col3] in df_dupes_list:
        df.drop(labels=i, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

This code should remove row 4.
In your desired output, you left row 5 for some reason. 
If you can explain why you left row 5 but kept row 0, then I can adjust my code to more accurately match your desired output.

Comment: rows 4 and 5 should both be removed as they have the same value in col1 and col2, and col3 is the opposite and they make up a pair.

Comment: @peter i kept row 0 because col1 and col2 matched but col3 wasn't the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I used @Petar Luketina code here with an adjustment and it worked. However I would like to use it for a massive dataset -> 1million rows and 43 columns. This code takes forever:

```
df_dupes = df[df['col3'].abs().duplicated(keep=False)]
df_dupes_list = df_dupes.to_numpy().tolist()
for i, row in df_dupes.iterrows():
    if row.col3 < 0 and [row.col1, row.col2, -row.col3] in df_dupes_list:
        print(row.col3)
        try:
            c = np.where((df['col1'] ==row.col1) & (df['col2'] ==row.col2) & 
                (df['col3'] ==-row.col3))[0][0]

            df.drop(labels=[i,df.index.values[c]], axis=0, inplace=True)
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for those people interested, here is an alternative that avoids iterating over the rows:

First use a flag to identify the pair of rows to be removed (row plus the next row when col1 and col2 are the same and col3 are the negative of each other)

```
df.loc[(df.col1 == df.col1.shift(1)) & (df.col2 == df.col2.shift(1)) & (df.col3 == -df.col3.shift(1)), 'removeFlag'] = True
df.loc[df.removeFlag.shift(-1) == True, 'removeFlag'] = True

   col1  col2  col3 removeFlag
0     1     1     1        NaN
1     2     2     2        NaN
2     1     1     1        NaN
3     3     5     7        NaN
4     1     2    -1       True
5     1     2     1       True
6     1     2     1        NaN
```

Then use this flag to delete to offending rows:

```
df = df[~(df.removeFlag == True)]
df.drop(columns=['removeFlag'], inplace=True)

   col1  col2  col3
0     1     1     1
1     2     2     2
2     1     1     1
3     3     5     7
6     1     2     1
```

This approach probably needs a little more refinement if row 6 had been the same as row 4 (ie the first half of a repeated identical pair) but you get the idea.